# Set user_id for nested_attribute in devise registration before user exists

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

The idea is simple.  I require a nested attribute `tag` for user registration.  `tag` requires a `user_id`.

**the view**

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: {role: :form}) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :tags, resource.tags.build do |a| %>
    <%= a.text_field :tagname %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**tag migration**

```
class CreateTags < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :tags do |t|
      t.string :tagname
      t.references :user, index: true

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :tags, :tagname, unique: true
  end
end
```

**the tag model**

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :user_id
  validates_uniqueness_of :tagname
end
```

**the user model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags, autosave: true, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags
end
```

**strong parameters**

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(
          :tags_attributes => [:id, :user_id, :tagname]
        ) }
```

The save feature is untouched at the moment.  The form passes the nested attribute :tagname just fine.  But I've been unable to get the "would be" `user_id` from `resource`.

I've already looked for hours online for any answer to this.  None has appeared, but the idea that the nested attribute should be saved after the initial user object is saved sounds like a workable solution.  But then it's no longer handled as a nested attribute.

Help is appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

Alright I solved it.  I bastardised my devise registrations controller a bit, but it works.

First I removed user_id verification from my tag model.

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates_uniqueness_of :tagname
end
```

I then proceeded with modifying the devise registration controller.

```
def create
  build_resource(sign_up_params)

  # added code begins here
  @tag = nil
  @tag.define_singleton_method(:valid?) {false}
  if params["user"].has_key? "tags_attributes"
    @tag = Tag.new(params["user"].delete("tags_attributes").values.first)
    if @tag.valid?
      resource_saved = resource.save # original line of code
    else
      resource.errors.add(*@tag.errors.first)
      flash.delete :tagname_error
      set_flash_message :alert, :tag_taken if is_flashing_format?
    end
  else
    set_flash_message :alert, :need_tag if is_flashing_format?
  end
  # end added code

  yield resource if block_given?
  if resource_saved
    if resource.active_for_authentication?
      set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_flashing_format?
      sign_up(resource_name, resource)

      # This is where current_user has been created and resource.id == current_user.id

      # begin added code
      @tag.user_id= resource.id
      # end added code

      respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    else
      set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_flashing_format?
      expire_data_after_sign_in!
      respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    end
  else
    clean_up_passwords resource
    @validatable = devise_mapping.validatable?
    if @validatable
      @minimum_password_length = resource_class.password_length.min
    end
    respond_with resource
  end
end
```

I've defined `:tag_taken` and `:need_tag` in my devise locales file for translations of the error string.

### And everything works!

*For the record this is in addition to the existing code in the question.*